# How to convert the encoding type of a stream in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, encoding, stream, streamreader

I ve the following stream but I don't know its encoding type because the stream reader detects encoding from byte order marks

```
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(respStream, True)
```

so how can I detect the encoding type AND convert it to another type? (for ex. from ASCII to UTF8)

> PS:
>
> What is the difference with the
>   following line?
>
> ```
> Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(respStream,
> ```
>
> Encoding.ASCII, True)

Thank You in advance,

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the StreamReader's [`CurrentEncoding` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.currentencoding.aspx), and you can write the string to a `StreamWriter` with a different Encoding.

To answer your unrelated question, that explicitly specifies the encoding.

Comment: StreamReader's Encoding property doesn' exists.

Comment: @Max: Sorry; `CurrentEncoding`.