# How to get the encoding type of a string?

Tags: .net, encoding, filestream, iostream, streamreader

With the following code, I get a string from a stream but I don't know the encoding type because it's detected automatically by StreamReader;

how can I get the encoding type of the string respHTML?

```
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(respStream, True)
Dim respHTML as String = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert the encoding type of a stream in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539999/how-to-convert-the-encoding-type-of-a-stream-in-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings contain Unicode characters, not bytes.
Encodings are ways to save Unicode characters as bytes; a string doesn't have any encoding.

You can get the encoding used by the *StreamReader* by checking the [`CurrentEncoding` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.currentencoding.aspx).